# go client example of a kafka consumer for confluent cloud with sasl.username and sasl.password

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

Does anyone have a go client example of a Kafka consumer for the confluent cloud with sasl.username and sasl.password?

I am running into an error while trying to consume a message from the confluent cloud.

```
Failed to connect to Kafka broker: kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to: EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confluent has their own repo for examples

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/confluent_cloud_example/confluent_cloud_example.go

Extract

```
    bootstrapServers          = "<BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS>"
    ccloudAPIKey              = "<CCLOUD_API_KEY>"
    ccloudAPISecret           = "<CCLOUD_API_SECRET>"
    schemaRegistryAPIEndpoint = "<CCLOUD_SR_ENDPOINT>"
    schemaRegistryAPIKey      = "<CCLOUD_SR_API_KEY>"
    schemaRegistryAPISecret   = "<CCLOUD_SR_API_SECRET>"
)

func main() {

    topic := "go-test-topic"
    createTopic(topic)

    // Produce a new record to the topic...
    producer, err := kafka.NewProducer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers": bootstrapServers,
        "sasl.mechanisms":   "PLAIN",
        "security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
        "sasl.username":     ccloudAPIKey,
        "sasl.password":     ccloudAPISecret})

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to create producer: %s", err))
    }

    client, err := schemaregistry.NewClient(schemaregistry.NewConfigWithAuthentication(
        schemaRegistryAPIEndpoint,
        schemaRegistryAPIKey,
        schemaRegistryAPISecret))
```